# The expected value of log Gamma function

Tags: expected-value, gamma-distribution, exponential-distribution, integral

Suppose $X$ is exponentially distributed with the rate parameter $\lambda$. If we have the expected value of $\log X$ as
\begin{equation}
\langle \log X\rangle=-\gamma-\log\lambda
\end{equation}
where $\gamma$ is the *Euler–Mascheroni* constant.

Now I am wondering how I can compute a lower bound for $X\log X-\log \Gamma(X)$ since this is a concave function?

I originally wanted to compute the following integral
\begin{equation}
\langle \log \Gamma(X)\rangle=-\exp(-\lambda X)\log\Gamma(X)+\int \psi(X)\exp(-\lambda X)\mathrm{d}X
\end{equation}
where $\psi(X)= \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}X}\log \Gamma(X)$.
I came across [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0031320318303789) which they are tackling more and less the same problem as mine and they suggested this bound:
\begin{equation}\label{eq:lb}
\begin{split}
    x\log x-\log\Gamma(x)&\ge x^*\log x^*-x^*-\log x^*-\log\Gamma(x^*)\\
    &+\Big(\log x^*-\frac{1}{x^*}-\psi(x^*)\Big)(x-x^*)+\log x+x
\end{split}
\end{equation}
It seems it works just for small $x^*$. I wonder whether there is a tighter bound or not? Any suggestion would be appreciate?

Comment: I wouldn't expect Stirling's asymptotic series to be a good approximation because it's poor for small values of $X.$ That will make it especially bad for large $\lambda,$ which concentrate most of the probability around small $X.$ You could, however, break the original integral into several pieces using the relation $\Gamma(z) = \Gamma(z+k)/(z(z+1)\cdots(z+k-1))$ for positive integers $k$ and approximating $\Gamma(z+k)$ with Stirling's expansion.  This could be extremely accurate.

Comment: I took a closer look at that suggestion, hoping that perhaps a partial fractions expansion of $1/(z\cdots(z+k-1))$ might produce integrals one could evaluate.  No such luck. Note that you can view this question as asking for the Laplace transform of $\log\Gamma$ (as defined on the positive reals), but no such transform is known.  I think you will need to settle for approximations.  Their form might vary depending on the magnitude of $\lambda.$

Comment: @whuber I need to compute this term because I have a mixture of Gamma distribution model and I am using variational method for the inference and I must find a good approximation of this $\langle\alpha\rangle\big(\langle\log\alpha\rangle-\langle\log\beta\rangle\big)-\langle\log\Gamma(\alpha)\rangle-(\langle\alpha\rangle-1)\langle\log X\rangle-\langle\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\rangle\langle X\rangle$ where $\alpha$ based on similar model that I worked with, would vary between 0.1 to 2 or something. Do you think the approximation that I suggested would be sufficient for this range?

Comment: The Stirling series is a poor approximation in that range.  Why not use numerical integration?

Comment: @whuber this is part of a model that was developed earlier by someone else and I am modifying the model based on my problem. The whole variational model is coded in matlab and no numerical integration was used earlier. If I can approximate this expectation with 10^-4 accuracy, I think it would be sufficient

Comment: Matlab is capable of performing numerical integration.  If the concern is that this might be inefficient, you can perform the calculation once and for all for a grid of values of $\lambda$ and compute an interpolating function.  You can make that as accurate as you like (within limits of floating point precision) and achieve an extremely fast implementation. Thus, the only reason to avoid this approach would be if you need to perform symbolic algebra on the expectation (or its approximation) for further analysis.

Comment: Is the question about approximating the distribution of $Y := g(X)$ when $g(x) := \log \Gamma(x) - x \log x$ and  $X$ is exponential with rate $\lambda$ or simply approximating the expectation of $Y$? Is a numerical approximation wanted, or closed form inequalities? Anyway, approximation of $\log \Gamma(x)$ for large $x$ works pretty well for say $x >3$. For small $x$ another simple approximation can be used as well.

Comment: @Yves the question is the former that you described and I am looking for a closed form inequality.